# Concurrent Garbage-Collectiong/Compacting Memory Allocator

Tags: concurrency, memory-allocation, garbage-collection

I'm developing an algorithm for concurrent heap garbage collection/compaction. It will be used in low latency systems that need to scale well to a lot of clients, e.g. web servers.

I thought about an algorithm that would be suitable but it does have a few flaws.
I'm not very good at describing algorithms, so please correct me if my description isn't clear, but here it goes:

- There are two heaps of equal size
- There's an object handle table, which contains memory address and lock of each object.
- The index to the handle table is the handle of an object.
- Each heap has a linked list of all objects, which contains type and size of the object.
- Objects are copied from one heap to another

The GC/compaction algorithm is designed to be incremental and concurrent.
This is the Pseudocode, which runs in all threads from time to time.
Atomic operations are marked with  `// atomic`.

```
current = heapFrom->currentCopyObj; // atomic
heapFrom->currentCopyObj = current->Next; // atomic

while(heapTo->currentCopyObj->freeSpaceToNextObj < current->size) // atomic
{
    heapTo->currentCopyObj = heapTo->currentCopyObj->Next; // atomic
}

size = current->Size;
oldAddress = current->Address;
newAddress = heapTo->currentCopyObj->Address;

handleTable->LockObj(current->Handle); // atomic

memcpy(heapTo->currentCopyObj->Address, current->Address, current->Size);

heapTo->InsertIntoObjectList(heapTo->currentCopyObj, current); // atomic
heapFrom->RemoveFromObjectList(current); // atomic

handleTable->SetHandleAddress(current->Handle, newAddress); // atomic

handleTable->UnlockObj(current->Handle); // atomic
```

Allocation of objects is done using a sort of bump allocator, which allocates objects at the end of each heap, handle allocation is done using an O(1) algorithm, which uses either a bump allocator or cached handle slots.
This should make allocation quite fast, O(1) theoretically.

This algorithm has a few flaws though:

- Object writes have to be locking, reads can be concurrent with copying
- It does not achieve very good heap compression
- High memory overhead due to handle table
- Not very cache friendly due to handle table

Would this algorithm work? If it would, how could I solve some of the problems it has?
Or is there a better algorithm that does not have these flaws?

Comment: I think you may have answered your own question. It would work, but it may not optimise for everything that you need to optimise for. Just as a curiosity, have you looked at any of the standard GC surveys, such as Paul Wilson's paper? https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~fp/courses/15411-f14/misc/wilson94-gc.pdf

Comment: I agree with @Pseudonym. I would research existing garbage collection algorithms – and existing garbage collector _implementations_ that could be dropped in as a library – quite a lot before being convinced that there is sufficient reason to design and implement a custom algorithm.

Comment: It would probably make more sense to provide several memory managers. First so that you can develop/test/refine/etc new managers. Second no two applications are alike and the ability to twiddle the implementation is a useful and desirable toggle for particular optimised software. Third, a Development memory manager that has extra book keeping for narrowing in on particular poorly behaving memory users is a good nice to have during debugging.

Comment: @Pseudonym Thanks, I'll take a lot at it. Maybe there's an algorithm I overlooked which fits my needs.

Comment: @Kain0_0 I think having the garbage collector/allocator abstracted would make developing and testing garbage collectors a lot easier